# Can I use actual iOS controls inside a Qt application?

Tags: ios, qt, uikit

Is there a way to use actual iOS controls inside a Qt application?  As one specific example, there is a [switch control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISwitch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISwitch-SW1) in iOS that has a very specific look that is quite different from the look of the [Qml switch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-switch.html) and I don't there is a QWidget that does quite the same thing ([QCheckBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html) is probably the closest).

Creating my own control where I build all the UI pieces so it looks like the actual iOS control is not an option, as one of the requirements I've been given is that the resulting program should match the control style of whichever iOS version it's installed on (within reason of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Find out if there's a way for iOS to render a control off-screen to a buffer. Then use that as an image for your control.
2. Make a proxy for the native control, and overlay it on top of your UI. The proxy should relay the position from QML to native, and the size and state from native to QML.
3. Have a short lived (could be just one frame) screen that renders the controls you wish, in the states you need, then capture that. This only makes sense if you can't render the controls off-screen.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, your #1 and #3 have the same basic idea: when my program starts up, have it capture the visual rendering of the controls I am using, and then have my control use those images to render itself.  The problem I see there is the transitions - again, using my example of the iOS switch control, there aren't just two visual states I need to capture, but all the transitions between the "on" and "off" states, and writing code that can (1) capture and then (2) render those images sounds exceptionally daunting!

Comment: Your #2 is intriguing, do you know offhand of any example code that shows how to write such a proxy?

Comment: #1 Is not the same idea as #3. #1 would allow you to use native controls cleanly from Qt Quick. Simply render them off-screen to a bitmap, and forward that to a Qt Quick control. It's exactly what native Qt styles do on the desktop: they render native controls off-screen, using native APIs.

Comment: OK, then I'm not following you.  If #1 has a control off-screen that I am rendering into a bitmap, that sounds a lot like #2.

Comment: @BettyCrokker #2 is rendering on-screen, overlaid on top of the view the Qt Quick scene is rendered into. `QWidget::winId` returns an `NSView`, so you can certainly stack things on top of it.

Comment: Interesting ... OK, if I understand now: with #1, the control is off-screen and I've got code that looks at it every X milliseconds and updates my on-screen control accordingly (so I capture any transitional states).  With #2, the control is on-screen so any transitional states are automatically displayed.  With either option, the answer to my original question is "Yes, but it isn't trivial".

Comment: @BettyCrokker Yeah, unfortunately it isn't trivial.